# what is Team Foundation Server in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

can anyone tell me what's role of TFS in VS2010? Is that Inbuilt in visual studio 2010 or Download it?

my second doubts i want to install TFS in VS2008. what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) is source control, time tracking and CI build system.

It costs [money](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13350), see [this question of MSDN social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsgeneral/thread/d0df8146-2109-429a-8277-cea705157bdb).

Comment: pl elaborate. I'm not understanding. I'm just check it out TFS is available in VS2010 Ultimate. In Tool -> Option -> Source Control -> Visual Studio TFS

Comment: @Jigs: Visual Studio Team Suite can be a **client** to Team Foundation **Server**

Answer (score 1):

It's the Microsoft way to implement Application LifeCycle Management (ALM)
It covers the main areas for Task management, source control, project Health status and so on.

It's a server which connects some microsoft products for an integrated software development management tool.

Also it has some nice features, the installation process and work to maintain it is a pain.
It's manilny based on Sql Server, SharePoint Services, and Reporting Services.

With other tools you would often have to  have multiple different tools form different companys.
One for builds, one for Task Management, one for statistics and so on.

There are some partner programs like [Bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) where you can get it "for free"

Answer (score 1):

TFS is an external service of Visual Studio. You can't "install it" in visual studio you have to install it on a server.

TFS have multiple usages,

- Source control (like SVN or GIT)
- Tasks manager (you can use it to follow tasks advancement)
- Builds manager (you can use it to automate your builds)

In other words TFS allow you to manage the "life" of your applications

TFS cost money and cannot be freely installed and used.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364061.aspx)

Comment: There are some subscription and partnerships which include the TFS. For Example the "nearly free" bizspark program